# 2 City Scheduling DP clarification

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

For the following problem from leetcode, would it be possible to structure my recurrence relation like this for using a DP approach:

OPT[i][w] = min{cost[I][0] + OPT[I+1][w-1], cost[I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPtQ0.png) + OPT[I+1][w]}

where OPT[I][w] represents the minimum cost of assigning the ith person to either city A or city B when city A has w more people that can move in before it reaches its capacity (essentially the current remaining capacity of city A). Choice 1 represents assigning the ith person to city A, and choice 2 represents assigning the ith person to city B.

So the min cost for this problem would be OPT[0][n], where we find the minimum cost of assigning the 0th indexed person on the costs list to city A with current remaining capacity of n people.  I realize that I'm not tracking the remaining capacity of city B, but I'm assuming that as long city A reaches n people then city B will reach n people at the end too?

I've attached a screenshot of the problem and my logic for constructing the recurrence relation below.
link to problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-city-scheduling/description/
[Recurrence Relation Logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLje.png)

[2 City Scheduling Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPtQ0.png)

Comment: Could you post the image of text as [actual text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), so it's accessible and searchable? Maybe a link to the problem would be good. Thanks.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your transition is. Have you tried to implement your idea or write some pseudocode?

Comment: Link to problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-city-scheduling/description/